How to interpret Frequency Response spec of Studio Monitor speakers
Hope I am on-topic here.
I am an amateur attempting to play my electric guitar thru Audio interface, Windows PC, a free Amp Sim and the output from the audio interface finally plugs into a basic 2.1 multimedia speakers!! Well not an ideal setup, but I am not into any kind of music production or so. Just a plain pass time hobby.
I have been exploring the specifications of a few Studio Monitor Speakers from known international brands. I am trying to interpret the way the Frequency Response is written in the manual.
-3 dB  80Hz – 20KHz
So, does it mean that anything below 80Hz can not be played by this speaker?
What is the significance of -3 dB? Does it mean that 80Hz sound will be quieter by about 3dB than average mid range?
Guitar Low E is I suppose somewhere 81Hz. And a bass Guitar has even lower frequencies than this. So will it be a bad idea to buy such a speaker for electric guitar playing?

The "frequency response" range gives you only a very rough idea of the speaker response. Any good manufacturer will also publish frequency response graph, such as this one for Yamaha HS5 with similar range:

Yamaha also gives 74 Hz–24 kHz range at -3dB and 54 Hz–30 kHz at -10 dB for these speakers. What they mean is "in this range the response does not drop below 3 (or 10) dB below the reference level (0 dB)". As the response exceeds the level marked as "0 dB" in some ranges, the exact interpretation might be subjective.
You are right that 80 Hz is a bit high, and won't allow you to control the bass/subbass range well. You either need a subwoofer, or use other speakers or headphones to check your mixes. Depending on how much your music relies on the low range, it might be more or less practical.
If you're asking about "playing" guitar - this might be a perfect range to practice and record guitar. Note that the fundamental frequencies of low guitar notes often aren't even the loudest, especially in sounds used in rock music. It will likely be also just fine for practicing bass guitar too, not necessarily for mixing, for the reasons mentioned earlier.

I've also thought that monitors could be as they are to emulate the sort of gear that the final mixes would be heard on by the majority of listeners - depending of course on what genre is being discussed.

Thank you very much for such a detailed explanation. Upvoted and accepted.

In terms of frequency response, those monitors will be completely sufficient for guitar. In particular, they will almost certainly be much better than the "basic multimedia speakers". For such speakers it wouldn't even make sense to measure a "-3 dB" range, because the spectrum is full of peaks and troughs. The hi-mid speakers of the 2.1 set probably reach down only to about 200 Hz. The subwoofer adds roughly the range from 60 Hz to 300 Hz, but those are generally very nonlinear.
For that matter, the speakers in a guitar cabinet are also very nonlinear. That's not only accepted but actually large part of what makes up the special character of each amp.
To understand why this isn't a big deal it is important to be clear that even a speaker that completely cuts everything below 100 Hz does not remove any tone below 100 Hz. What these numbers refer to is the Fourier decomposition of the signal. For a guitar this boils down to, every tone consists of a fundamental (the nominal frequency) plus a lot of harmonic overtones, for the 82.5 Hz low E string that would be 165 Hz, 247.5 Hz, 330 Hz, 412.5 Hz and so on - integer multiples of the fundamental. (Approximately.) So everything except the fundamental is actually well in the range of what the monitors can transmit, and those harmonics actually make up most of the sound character.
All that said, there is a different reason why the studio monitors may not be super satisfying: simple lack of volume. Guitar amps can be seriously loud even at small size because they don't mind taking everything to the limit - meaning you get not only the clean signal but lots of gritty distortion. Again this is not seen as a problem but part of "the right sound". The amp circuitry is specifically designed to do "soft clipping", meaning the distortion is smooth and, well, electric-guitary.
With multimedia speakers it's not so extreme, here distortion would not be used deliberately - but the manufacturer would try to get as much sound pressure as possible out of the things, even if it requires sacrificing clarity.
For studio monitors however this would be completely unacceptable: they must be able to clearly represent the original input, regardless of the volume setting. Which means the amp is specifically designed to avoid distortion. Until you try to crank it even more and run into a hard limit, which sounds really nasty.
If you're ok with low volume this is not an issue, but playing guitar through a very low volume amp can feel kind of weird because the "pling-pling" from the strings is so noticeable.

I'm not so sure about the lack of volume. Even the multimedia speaker sized near field monitors tend to be around 50W per speaker and that's a lot when the speakers are at computer screen distance.

@ojs "tend to"? Yes it's possible to cram that much power into small speakers with modern amp topology and rare-earth speakers, but certainly not all monitors do that. In my experience the ones that do are either quite expensive, or they don't actually have the fidelity I'd demand from a studio monitor. Could be that this has changed in the last 10 years though. Anyway, 50W-peak of a monitor gives much lower SPL-RMS than a 50W guitar amp would. (Well... a 50 W guitar amp is way to loud for a living room!)

I believe you understand the point even though you don't really admit it. Guitar amps are about as loud as hi-fi gear with 10 or 100 times the power, but 0.5W guitar amp is already well loud enough to overpower the acoustic noise electric guitar makes.

Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. I have Upvoted your answer.
